# Emoji creation discord.js v14

Tags: discord, discord.js

Any idea on how to create an emoji on discord.js v14. The docs are not really helping?

Used to do this in discord.js V13

> const emoji = await message.guild.emojis.create(emojiLink, emojiName);

But it doesn't work anymore ([ANTI-CRASH] Unhandled Rejection: TypeError [ReqResourceType]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.).

The code (partially) in case it is any kind of help:

```js
 const modifiedLink = emojiURL.replace(substringToRemove, "");
    const modifiedLink2 = substringToAdd + modifiedLink + substringToAddEnd;
    const modifiedLink3 = modifiedLink2.replace(ReplaceEmote, "emote")?.trim();

    console.log(modifiedLink3);



   

    // Use the temporary file to create a new custom emoji
    const emoji = await message.guild.emojis.create(modifiedLink3, emojiName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The docs are not really helping?

This is a very interesting statement. [Let's take a look.](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.13.0/class/GuildEmojiManager?scrollTo=create)

There is only 1 parameter called `options`. There are also 2 examples stating how to use the method. To me, this is crystal clear—compare what you're doing with the working example and you'll see what you're doing wrong.